# Spark iterative Algorithm UDF gets triggered multiple times in each iteration

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am running an iterative loop in Spark.
Each iteration generates a dataframe which then becomes the input of next iteration.
The program contains a UDF which is called in each iteration. After each iteration i assign the value to a new dataframe and  write the old dataframe to hdfs. The new dataframe then becomes the input of my next iteration.
The problem i observe is that my UDF gets invoked multiple times. The DAG gets longer each timestep and UDF gets called multiple times.
How can i prevent this behavior. I would not be using cache and/or checkpoint due to performance reasons and at the same time i cannot afford UDF getting invoked multiple times.

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible. Can you maybe paste some of your code please?

Answer (score 0):

I got your point buddy!

You can use:

```
tesd1Df =test1Df.sqlContext.createDataFrame(test1Df.rdd, test1Df.schema).cache()
```

The above way similar to checkpoint but instead of saving the dataframe physically it just cache it.

It won't affect your performance, I have been in the same situation and I have observed a drastic improvement of performance.

This way I use in Spark ML too but the thing is you need to watch out for your In-memory space capacity otherwise this method will work.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot afford to cache and unpersist in each iteration. I was able to break the lineage by writing to hdfs and then reading back from hdfs in each iteration. Performance is now actually better that cache.

Comment: Yeah exactly what I mentioned in my answer checkpoint saves your dataframe in hdfs. So are performing checkpoint ? Or just writing to hdfs ?

Comment: Writing to hdfs

Comment: Can you explain how checkpoint affects your performance because as far as I know it writes the dataframe to hdfs and reads it back the same thing whatvyou are doing.